# Measure query execution time in stored procedure - occasionally unexpected values

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure in SQL Server to measure query execution time. The SQL code to be executed can be passed via procedure parameter (`@SqlCommand`) and it gets executed by system procedure `sp_executesql`.

```
Create procedure [dbo].[spExecuteSql]
 @SqlCommand nvarchar(max),
 @tTIME int OUTPUT
as 

    

begin
 CHECKPOINT;  DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;  DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
 declare @t0 datetime2 = GETDATE()

   exec dbo.sp_executesql @stmt = @SqlCommand

 declare @t1 datetime2 = GETDATE()

 set @tTIME = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@t0,@t1)
 select @tTIME
end
```

I call this procedure in c# app in visual studio, values returned by procedure are usually as expected and quite similar for the same query, but from time to time the measured time is much higher.

On the graph below I present the time series obtained by calling my procedure N times with the same query as a parameter.
Time - Y axis, number of iteration - X axis.

[First graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9lTK.png)

[Second graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYOPa.png)

Could anyone tell me why the query execution time can sometimes differ that much and how I could resolve this issue?

When I call this procedure N times directly in SQL Server, the unexpected results appear less often, but still every 30 measures one of them can be much higher.
I call procedure in SQL Server like this:

```
declare @i integer = 0
declare @itrs integer = 50
while @i < @itrs
   begin
         exec dbo.spExecuteSql @SqlCommand = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Comments] AS [c] WHERE [c].[Score] > 100', @tTIME = 0

         set @i = @i + 1
   end
```

Comment: What are the units of time on the Y-axes? Microseconds? The `datetime` data type has a resolution of ticks, 300 ticks per second or 3.33' milliseconds. Consider using the `datetime2` data type instead which has a resolution of 100 nanoseconds.

Comment: FYI - the `RETURN` statement of a SP is for returning a status of the SP i.e. it ran correctly or not. For returning a value you should be using an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: When you measured this performance was there any other processes accessing the database at the same time?

Comment: I think as suggested by AlwaysLearning that using milliseconds is not really accurate enough - the difference between procedures that run in only a few milliseconds is not adequately captured (also not very important unless you are working in environments requiring very high performance characteristics - a few milliseconds is a blink of an eye in human terms). Note that if you are clearing the buffers then the query may work differently in "real life" as well. Also, clock times are always subject to variation - the performance can be affected by other things going on at runtime.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I updated the procedure (and the post) following your tips, but the results I get are still the same.

Comment: @DaleK thank you very much, I updated my procedure to use `OUTPUT`. 

There shoud not be any other process, all the other apps are closed during the measurements (except of c# app in visual studio that calls the procedure N times and saves the results), database is local. Is there a chance that MS SQL can do any "background" processes in this case?